# Build for multiple configurations in TFS Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is it possible to make TFS Build 2017 to build binaries for all this configuration combinations:

- VS2015, VS2017
- Win32, x64
- Debug, Release

Do I have to make a build step for each of this combinations, or can I use some sort of magic to do everything in a simple way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable Multi-configuration in Options tab of build definition. Article: [How do I build multiple configurations for multiple platforms?](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/visual-studio-build#how-do-i-build-multiple-configurations-for-multiple-platforms)

[image]

[image]

After that, it will split configurations to multiple builds during the build.

[image]

For different vs versions, you need to add another step/task and select corresponding vs version.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to pair these configurations? Such as building only Win32 with VS2015 and x64 with VS2017? I'm getting a situation like this because coded UI tests can't be ran in x64.

Comment: On **Azure DevOps Server / Services (TFS > v2018)**, for the new yaml / yml pipeline files, the solution can be found here [MS Docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multi-configuration)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the configurations that you want to build right on the compilation build step. Fill out the "configurations" text box with "release, debug" and the platform with "x86, x64".

You will need two steps for Visual Studio version...