# Build for multiple configurations in TFS Build on different Platforms

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, cross-platform, tfsbuild

I would like to run the same build definiton twice for multiple configurations on different platforms.

My use case is a CMake build which must be executed for Linux and Windows. Currently we have separate build definitions, which proofs harder to maintain instead of doing one that is platform independent.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261072/build-for-multiple-configurations-in-tfs-build) I can use multiconfiguration for this. However, i cannot specify different demands for these configurations.

We currently have TFS2017 on premise here. I also checked the *latest* Version on VSTS, but i could not find a solution.

Comment: What's that mean for "`i cannot specify different demands for these configurations.`"?  Do you mean that you want to build the multiple configurations on different build agents?

Comment: Exactly. I cannot build for Windows and Linux on the same agent!

Answer (score 0):

We can set demands to specify **only one** agent within a build definition.

So, in your scenario you can create separate build definitions just as you did,  specify different demands to build the multiple configurations on different agents.

Another workaround is building them with Release definition, you can use multiple Environments or [Multiple phases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/multiple-phases?view=vsts&tabs=web), then add corresponding tasks similar as in build definition to build them. Thus you can set the demands for each of the agent phases.

[image]

Comment: We use Release definitions for the release process. Using this as build also seems ugly and would mess up our process. Therefore we stick to multiple definition for now, keeping them as small as possible with the most of the logic in the repositories script files.